# selenium-wire blocking connection due to proxy config

Tags: firefox, proxy, webdriver, seleniumwire

I'm using selenium-wire and the firefox webdriver to access a website (online game). I am running a python script on my local network and no proxy is needed to access the Internet.

Here is a extract on my code:

```py
#!C:/Python38-32/python.exe
    
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

# Go to the home page
driver.get('https://fr0.forgeofempires.com/page/')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
iframe_switched = driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    
useridInput = driver.find_element_by_id('login_userid')
useridInput.click();
    
useridInput.send_keys('myuser'); 

login_passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_id('login_password')
login_passwordInput.click();

login_passwordInput.send_keys('mypass'); 

loginButton = driver.find_element_by_id('login_Login')
loginButton.click();

defaultContent_switched = driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "play_now_button"))
)
play_nowButton = driver.find_element_by_id('play_now_button')
play_nowButton.click();

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "ServerName"))
)
Button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('ServerName')
Button.click();
```

Everything works fine until this point. The page is now supposed to load the game at a new URL (https://xxx.forgeofempires.com/game) but it gets stuck. If I hit F5 I get **The proxy server is refusing connections**. I went to my Firefox proxy settings and noticed that they changed from **No proxy** or **Use system proxy settings** to **Manual 127.0.0.1**. I guess it it Selenium-wire changing that in order to inspect the traffic?

[image]

My ultimate goal is to catch XHR responses generated ny the page, that's why I use Selenium-wire.

What could cause the localhost proxy to get blocked when connecting to the website? How can I fix that?

If I replace

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
```

by

```py
from selenium import webdriver  # Import from selenium
```

it works fine, but then I won't be able to catch the XHR responses. I have also tried mitmproxy but didn't managed to get it working.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've made a fully non-working example which shows that there is something wrong done by Selenium-wire. In the example below, the result page of Google cannot be loaded.

```py
#!C:/Python38-32/python.exe
    
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
#from selenium import webdriver  # Import from selenium

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

driver.maximize_window()

# Go to the home page
driver.get('https://www.google.se/')

useridInput = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
useridInput.click();
    
useridInput.send_keys('test'); 

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added this line in the end to make it work:

```py
value = input("SCRIPT ENDED\n")
```

The reason for that can be found [here](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/136#issuecomment-661707595) and below:

> Selenium Wire works by transparently configuring the browser to point
> at Selenium Wire's own proxy server. That proxy server (running on
> 127.0.0.1:49818 in your example above) is used to capture requests made by the browser whilst Selenium Wire is running. After Selenium
> Wire ends, it shuts down its proxy server because it thinks it's done.
> However, if the browser is left open (which seems to be the case in
> your example above), the browser will still be pointing at the proxy
> server. Trying to use the browser will not work, because the proxy
> server has now gone away with the shutdown of Selenium Wire.
>
> If you wish to manually interact with the browser, you'll need to keep
> Selenium Wire running by ensuring that your program does not end. You
> could potentially use a time.sleep() for that, or perhaps some other
> mechanism such as input().